# Trying to use miredo, missing libtun6.so.0

Tags: networking, ipv6, tunnel, shared-libraries, teredo

I am trying to use miredo,

but when I run `sudo miredo`, I get `miredo: error while loading shared libraries: libtun6.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Using Debian 10.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: How did you install miredo?

Comment: Try to follow [this procedure](https://itsfoss.com/solve-open-shared-object-file-quick-tip/) for `libtun6`.

Comment: @user1686 Get source and follow building instructions in the readme

Comment: Thanks @harrymc , mind posting an answer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is based on the article
[How To Solve “cannot open shared object file” Error in Ubuntu-based Linux Distributions](https://itsfoss.com/solve-open-shared-object-file-quick-tip/),
where one can find more details about the procedure for `libgobject`.

**Method 1 : ldconfig**

The following command might rebuild some missing links:

```
sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v
```

**Method 2 : identify and install missing lib**

Find the installed version:

```
apt search libgobject
```

List all possible variants of the library to find the one related
to your program:

```
apt search --names-only gobject
```

Once the required package is identified:

```
sudo apt install package_name
sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v
```